# Heroku limitations and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a wordpress site hosted on heroku. We are storing our uploads to S3 with "WP Offload S3 Lite" plugin but when we are uploading a big file (approximately more than 1MB) it throws http error due to heroku restriction regarding post limit (it can't be more than 30 seconds).

What is the recommended approach for handling it? We need to upload it to heroku first as we have to resize it in case of an image, so direct upload isn't an option. Any other recommendation? is there a way for a background job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chunked file uploading should be a solid solution for your problem, you can try these:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-uploader/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tuxedo-big-file-uploads/

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you can check if your site has big enough `upload_max_filesize` (see official [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#php-runtime-settings) how to see and fix that)

Also, you can try to set these variables in code:

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
ini_set('memory_limit', '1000M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '1920');
```

Comment: Already have done this, it is sure a problem of script limitation, it does not have any relation with php specifically. I am checking if there is some way to use the pass-through and if it is already ready and implementee or any other way.